# Looking for short horror story about a dog

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

I think the story I’m looking for is from a book of short stories from the 80s or early 90s, all horror.

It was about a man who is stuck in his chair because his dog has turned on him. It won’t let him leave the chair.  The entire story is the tension between him and the dog while the police and townspeople are trying to help from outside.

The twist at the end is the dog is protecting him; the people outside are not human.

I thought it was by Robert McCammon but I can’t find it.

Comment: If it's indeed RobertMcCammon, it might be [on his website](https://www.robertmccammon.com/short-fiction/).